# Can not find BottomSheetDialogFragment in Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.1

Tags: android, xamarin, android-support-library, bottom-sheet

I have just upgraded all Support libraries in my Xamarin Android project from 25.3.1 to 25.4.0.1. My project is now impossible to compile (everything compiled and worked fine before upgrading) because of one custom dialog subclassing `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Visual Studio marks it red and says it can not find it ("The type or namespace BottomSheetDialogFragment could not be found").

In Object Browser I can not find `BottomSheetDialogFragment` in the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` library either.

[image]

If I change my custom dialog to subclass `AppCompatDialogFragment` instead everything compiles and works fine (except that the dialog is now lacking the Bottom Sheet behavior).

Has anybody had similar problems? Do you have any idea where the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

Xamarin has released version `25.4.0.2` which corrects the issue:

```
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
```

#### Original:

That version (and others?) of `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` `v25.4.0.1` is just broken... besides `BottomSheetDialogFragment`; `CheckableImageButton`, `AnimationUtils`, `ValueAnimatorCompat`, etc.. are missing (There are *over* 50 public classes were missing).

The odd thing is the correct `.jar` is embedded as those classes and pulling those libraries from Google's Maven in AS works fine:

```
dependencies {
   ~~~
   compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
   ~~~
}
```

i.e. The `BottomSheetDialogFragment` class exists in the `classes.jar` that gets extracted from `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design`:

```
strings __library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/library_project_imports/bin/classes.jar|grep -R BottomSheetDialogFragment
(standard input):android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.classUT
(standard input):android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.classUT
```

We are building our own Xamarin [AndroidSupportComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents) with custom bindings in order to get the latest and greatest as we are already using [26.0.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-1) in custom builds for Android Oreo.

It should be reported as a bug @ https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: I have rolled back to 25.3.1 and filed a bug as you advised here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59021. Thank you.

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina Thanks for the bugzilla link.  Looks like v25.4.0.2 will be out shortly to fix this....

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina `25.4.0.2` was released as a fix to the issue.